# JavaScript new Function to parse JSON String

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, function, new-operator

I am creating a script that parses the "rel" attribute of an anchor tag for a JSON String of settings. I am currently using something like this code to convert the string into a JavaScript Object:

```
var settings = new Function("return " + relAttribute);
```

Is this a good way to parse a JSON String?

Comment: Nope, it's not ;) It's pretty much like using `eval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you [json2.js](http://json.org/js.html) and the `JSON.parse` method. Example:

```
var settings = JSON.parse('{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }');
alert(settings.key2);
```

Answer (score 0):

first, the var settings will be a function, not the object. You have to evaluate that.

second, that's fine, but the malicious code may still break free of your function by hooking on the global scope, such as `window`.

then, you will have trouble with line breaks.